# multiplas timezone php

Tags: php, timestamp, timezone

Bom, tenho um sistema onde preciso usar um timestamp no formato UTC, e uso um sistema para mostra quando o perfil foi visitado no site, ai atualiza com um timestamp, porém tenho um problema, no site quando atualiza ele, ele diz que o perfil foi atualiza a 3h a mais, eu preciso usar UTC pois é necessário esse timezone para receber informações de uma api externa, como faço para tornar esse timestamp normal, e funcionar corretamente no site mostrando que foi atualizado na hora?

Comment: Isto esta se parecendo com erro comum em hospedagens, você está utilizando localhost, ou algum servidor pago? a resposta do @WictorChaves está correta, mas precisa saber quais definições do php podem ser editadas caso seja um servidor pago e se este for caso pode ser que eles já possuam uma `wiki` para este fim.

Comment: não é um error, eu uso um dedicado, acho que não fui claro, eu uso uma api para receber informações externas, estatisticas de perfis, para acessar api eu sou obrigado a usar UTC que é o horario do servidor que fornece acesso a api, meu servidor e site por outro lado, são br, eu teria que converter o resultado que a api me envia para o fuso horario brasileiro também

Comment: O `timestamp` que você menciona na pergunta se refere a uma tabela do banco que salva o horário a cada nova interação usando `current timestamp`? ou é uma variável `php` que pega o horário atual e salva no banco de dados?

Comment: uma variavel que pega valor atual de outro servidor.

Answer (score 3):

Carlos se entendi a sua pergunta é esta resposta que irá atender a sua necessidade, antes de mais nada seria ideal você dar uma lida na [documentação](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php) e entender o funcionamento do `timezone` e do `datetime` do `php`.

No seu sistema você deve receber a váriavel e seta-lá com o timezone desejado, no seu caso São Paulo.

```
new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
```

Receber a váriavel por parametro e setar a mesma com este timezone

```
$date = new DateTime('2017-10-14 10:04:59 GMT'); //entre os ( ) irá sua variável
$date->setTimezone($tz);
```

pronto sua váriavel foi setada com o `timezone` desejado, e nesse momento você pode utliza-lá para salvar no banco, mas é importante a leitura da documentação pois neste momento você implementá-la de diversar formas, eu fiz de duas forma apenas para exemplificar seu caso, mas na documentação você entenderá as diversas formas de se fazer.

> `echo $date->format('Y-m-d g:i:s A');`

Resultado: **2017-10-14 7:04:59 AM**

> `echo $date->format('l F j Y g:i:s A');`

Resultado: **Saturday October 14 2017 7:04:59 AM**

> O código completo fica assim:

```
$tz = new DateTimeZone('America/Sao_Paulo');
$date = new DateTime('2017-10-14 10:04:59 GMT'); // aqui dentro dos parenteses você deve coloca a sua váriavel DateTime($variavel);
$date->setTimezone($tz); //seta o timezone da váriavel
echo $date->format('Y-m-d g:i:s A'); //imprime o horário no padrão do timezone
echo '<br>';
echo $date->format('l F j Y g:i:s A');
```

E você pode testar neste [LINK](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/m6h0-tpvq)

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue alterar no servidor, ou desta forma no próprio php:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s');
?>
```

Se precisar de outras regiões: http://br.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Se você tiver acesso aos arquivos do servidor:

**httpd.conf**

SetEnv TZ America/Sao_Paulo

**php.ini**

date.timezone = "America/Sao_Paulo"

**my.ini**

default-time-zone = "America/Sao_Paulo"

Comment: na verdade, e eu poder usar diferentes timezone e fazer com que elas trabalhem sincronizadas, exemplo usar Sao paulo como padrão, mas na api usar a UTC e converter para são paulo o resultado quando for inserir no banco de dados