# PHP retornando hora atual errada

Tags: php, data

Estou com um problema ao usar a função `date` usando os parâmetros para retornar a hora atual.

Quando utilizo a função:

```
$hora = date('H:i:s');
```

Quando dou um `echo` na variável `$hora` para verificar, tenho o seguinte resultado:

```
14:45:21
```

Porém agora são 09:45.

Existe algum configuração do PHP ou do Xampp que possa estar alterando o horário?

A data está retornando corretamente, porem a hora não.

Comment: Provavelmente é a configuração do fuso horário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245778/112052

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No arquivo php.ini você tem que mudar a timezone.

Se você usa Xampp você encontra o arquivo em xampp\php\php.ini

Basta mudar a linha abaixo ou acrescenta-lá, após isso reinicie o apache do Xampp e tente novamente.

```
date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo
```

Answer (score 6):

Está pegando o horário do servidor.

Para corrigir basta usar o `date_default_timezone_set` do php.

Para o horário de Brasília use: `'America/Sao_Paulo'`. Outros fusos horários você encontra [aqui](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/timezones.php).

O código vai ficar assim:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
$hora = date('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');` para configurar seu fuso

Answer (score -2):

Erro comum: alterar o código do php.ini da linha 975(mais ou menos):

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = America/Sao_Paulo // linha 975
```

Mas na verdade você deve alterar na linha 1969:

```
[Date]
date.timezone=America/Sao_Paulo //linha 1969
```

Comment: Esse *php.ini* está com a diretiva `date.timezone` duplicada e a ultima atribuição é que tem precedência.